# Dispatching Queue Jobs (local Dev Mac) Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I try to dispatch a job on my local dev machine.

I setup my .env and queue config ; QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

I also did the migrate :

php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate

Then create my job something like : myjob::dispatchNow();

And finally run my worker: php artisan queue:work

With all that the code launch and execute well but not the job. The job is not created in the database jobs table. (nor in faield_jobs

Is I am missing any step?

Do I need something else on my local machine to run jobs queue?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [synchronous dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#synchronous-dispatching) by using `myjob::dispatchNow()`. The database does not need to be involved as it runs the job during the same request and your queue worker never knows about it. It is equivalent to having `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`.

If you use `myjob::dispatch()` before you start the queue worker, you will see the job in your database.